# F# return sorting indices from array.sort

Tags: f#, functional-programming

For an F# array, is there an easy way to return sorting indices along with the sorted array?

Like the `sort()` function from Matlab?

Background: I came from matlab/R, where manipulating array on indices are essential.

I'd like to reproduce some index functions and trying to be able to pass indices array around as a variable in various functions. for this `sort()` function, one usage would be sorting several aligned arrays together based on any one of them.

Maybe there are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Array.sort in combination with Array.mapi.

```
let arr = [| 14;3;11;2 |]
let sortedWithIndex = arr |> Array.mapi (fun x t -> (t,x)) |> Array.sort 
printfn "%A" sortedWithIndex
```

output

```
[|(2, 3); (3, 1); (11, 2); (14, 0)|]
```

Comment: Array.sort doesn't return the sorted array but sorts in place returning `unit`. The order of sorting/zipping is wrong too.

Comment: @Dario - `Array.sort` does not sort in place, it returns a new array.  The aptly named `Array.sortInPlace` is used to sort an array in place.  However you're right about the order of mapping and sorting being wrong.

Comment: I've corrected the order of sorting and mapping.  I actually thought the OP was looking for the indexes to be applied after the sort.  Oh well. Fixed now.  @Dario: Array.sort does not sort in place.

Comment: In F# 1.9.6.2 it does ;) Well, it's ok then

Comment: I guess you need to reverse x and t: Array.mapi (fun x t -> (t,x)) ?

Comment: @ahala I edited the answer to put them in the correct order.  This works correctly in F# 1.9.9.9

Answer (score 0):

```
let sortWithIndex list =
    list
    |> List.mapi (fun index x -> (x, index))
    |> List.sort
```

(Depending on the version of F#, `List.sort` might require a comparison function like `compare ).

Comment: the last step "|> List.sort compare" gives error on my machine:
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    ('a * int) list -> 'b    
but here has type
    'c list

Comment: `List.sort` doesn't take a comparison function (and because of the ordering of your tuple, does not need one).

Comment: @kvb: In my version it does (1.9.6.2) ;)

Comment: fair enough.  In 1.9.9.9, the function with that signature is `List.sortWith`.